# How to easily handle urlencoded links with many %?

Tags: xetex

I have a link like this:

```
    % Works:
    \href{https://www.google.com}{中国药科大学}

    % Does not work:
\href{https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E8%8D%AF%E7%A7%91%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6/248835}{中国药科大学}
```

What should I do to make the link work? I don't want to add `\` before each `%`. I have already tried:

```
    \href{\url{balabalabala.....}}{中国药科大学}
```

which did not work. I have also tried:

```
    \urldef{\UniversityIntro}\url{balabalabala....}
   
    \href{\UniversityIntro}{中国药科大学}
```

which did not work. What should I do to handle the href url to make it work as a url in latex? Not a view issue:

[image]

when I add the zh words `中`, show error like that.

```
\cventry{2009.09-2013.06}{本科}{\href{https://www.google.com/中}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{\emph{中国药科大学}}}}}{江苏南京}{\textit{信息管理与信息系统专业}}{}
```

I am using modernCV to write a personal resume right now. This is the full document:

```
%% start of file `template-zh.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv 主题
\moderncvstyle{classic}                        % 选项参数是 ‘casual’, ‘classic’, ‘oldstyle’ 和 ’banking’
\moderncvcolor{black}                          % 选项参数是 ‘blue’ (默认)、‘orange’、‘green’、‘red’、‘purple’ 和 ‘grey’
%\nopagenumbers{}                             % 消除注释以取消自动页码生成功能

% 字符编码
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % 替换你正在使用的编码
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
% 调整页面出血
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % 如果你希望改变日期栏的宽度
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}                 %段落缩进

% 个人信息
\name{John}{}
\title{软件开发(Java)}                     % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
%\address{街道及门牌号}{邮编及城市}            % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\extrainfo{性别：男~~出生日期：1991年3月}                 % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{IcdU7}                  % ‘64pt’是图片必须压缩至的高度、‘0.4pt‘是图片边框的宽度 (如不需要可调节至0pt)、’picture‘ 是图片文件的名字;可选项、如不需要可删除本行
%\quote{引言(可选项)}                          % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行

% 显示索引号;仅用于在简历中使用了引言
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother

\urldef{\UniversityIntro}\url{http://www.w3.org/file%query}

% 分类索引
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            内容
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}   
             
\maketitle

\section{教育背景}
%\cventry{2006.09-2009.06}{高中}{重庆市大足中学}{重庆大足}{\textit{理科}}{}  % 第3到第6编码可留白
\cventry{2009.09-2013.06}{本科}{\href{\url{https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E8%8D%AF%E7%A7%91%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6/248835}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{\emph{中国药科大学}}}}}{江苏南京}{\textit{信息管理与信息系统专业}}{}  % 第3到第6编码可留白
\clearpage

\end{document}

%% 文件结尾 `template-zh.tex'.
```

what I want to do is add the link with the University name and click the name to link with a website. Seems no matter what I try, it did not work. this is the website link: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E8%8D%AF%E7%A7%91%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6/248835

I am using latexmk to compile the pdf right now, this is the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 当使用未初始化的变量时，程序自动退出
# 也可以使用命令 set -o nounset
set -u

# 当任何一行命令执行失败时，自动退出脚本
# 也可以使用命令 set -o errexit
set -e

set -x

/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./output"
```

and Edit the tex using visual studio code. Did any suggestion to make it work? tried like this works:

```
https://baike.baidu.com/item/\%E4\%B8\%AD\%E5\%9B\%BD\%E8\%8D\%AF\%E7\%A7\%91\%E5\%A4\%A7\%E5\%AD\%A6/248835
```

but this way is so ugly.

Comment: Maybe it is a viewer issue? For me the version with the `%` signs works, and alternatively `\href{https://baike.baidu.com/item/中国药科大学/248835}{University Intro}` works as well. With 'works' I mean that the link is displayed in the PDF and when I click it my browser takes me to the correct page. Compiled with XeLaTeX, viewed with Evince (on Linux), with Firefox as browser. Could you give some more details on your exact setup?

Comment: which viewer do you use?

Comment: @Marijn using 中国药科大学 in the url is not reliable, it can work but it actually violates the spec.

Comment: It works? why did not work in my latex document.@Marijn

Comment: @UlrikeFischer unicode urls seem to be supported by the major browsers for some time now, so you could say it is reliable in most cases even if it is not in the spec.

Comment: @Dolphin to be sure you should provide a full document that shows the error. You can remove all non-relevant parts, but leave the documentclass, packages, font setup, and the cventry.

Comment: you can't use that in the argument of another command.

Comment: @Marijn are you sure? Mostly when I copy an URL with non-ascii letters which are show in the URL field of the browser, the URL I get in the copy is urlencoded

Comment: @daleif as I understand it the 'actual' url is percent-encoded to comply with the spec, and the browser handles the conversion from and to unicode when it comes to typing in the address bar, showing the address bar, copy-pasting from and to the address bar, and opening links clicked in external programs like pdf viewers. In Firexfox when I copy the full url from the address bar the pasted text is percent-encoded, but if I copy only the part after the `/` then the pasted text is utf8.

Comment: @Marijn as this is about a pdf the question is not what browsers supports but how pdf viewer handle such an url.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is also about browser support, if the viewer supports it but the browser doesn't then you're out of luck. Regarding pdf viewers: there seem to be some problems with PDFkit (I found a hyperref Github issue about this with you participating in the discussion) so indeed this may be prohibitive when sending your CV to other people. But for more controlled use cases using unicode urls can still be convenient, also I wouldn't be surprised if the spec adopts this practise at some point since the usage is increasing.

Comment: @Marijn the problem is not the url with non-ascii char in itself. urls with chinese work fine in a pdf, but how it should be encoded internally. The spec clearly requires percent encoding, and if use something else you are relying on heuristics in the viewer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand that, but if the heuristics are good then it will 'just work'. And in many cases (both browsers and pdf viewers) they are indeed good as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Ulrike in comments you cannot have `\href` or `\url` commands as an argument to another command because the contents of the url argument is treated verbatim. So something like

`\cventry{...}{\href{...}{...}}{...}`

is not allowed.

A workaround for this specific situation is to take the definition of the `\cventry` command from the `moderncv` source, split it in a part before the institution/employer argument and a part after it, then use `\href` in the main document between the two parts. In code:

```
\entryleft{years}{title}
\href{url}{caption}
\entryright{location}{description}
```

Full MWE, containing the definitions copied from `moderncvbodyi.sty` (the default body style for moderncv):

```
%% start of file `template-zh.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                        % 选项参数是 ‘casual’, ‘classic’, ‘oldstyle’ 和 ’banking’
\moderncvcolor{black}                          % 选项参数是 ‘blue’ (默认)、‘orange’、‘green’、‘red’、‘purple’ 和 ‘grey’
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % 替换你正在使用的编码
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC} % just for testing
% 调整页面出血
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % 如果你希望改变日期栏的宽度
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}                 %段落缩进

% 个人信息
\name{John}{}
\title{软件开发(Java)}                     % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\extrainfo{性别：男~~出生日期：1991年3月}                 % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行

% definitions copied from moderncvbodyi.sty
\newcommand{\entryleft}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
\raggedleft\hintstyle{#1} &  {\bfseries #2},%
}
\newcommand{\entryright}[2]{%
, #1, \textit{#2}.\strut%
\end{tabular}%
\par%
}

\begin{document}   
             
\maketitle

\section{教育背景}
\cventry{2006.09-2009.06}{高中}{重庆市大足中学}{重庆大足}{\textit{理科}}{}  % 第3到第6编码可留白

\entryleft{2009.09-2013.06}{本科}
\href{https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E8%8D%AF%E7%A7%91%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6/248835}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{\emph{中国药科大学}}}}
\entryright{江苏南京}{信息管理与信息系统专业}
\clearpage

\end{document}

%% 文件结尾 `template-zh.tex'.
```

Result:

[image]

And, importantly, the link works :) Note that I simplified the `\cventry` code a bit, now it no longer handles optional arguments, empty arguments, font settings. So maybe some tweaking is needed in case you want to use more or different arguments. I also changed the main font for testing but of course this is not relevant for the solution.